# How to handle text from API in flutter

Tags: flutter

**How to handle text from API in flutter, the text creates a new line, but it's not time yet**

[image]

**i want is like this**

[image]

Comment: Add extra details what do you want?

Comment: the text continue line, dont create new line because not finished yet

Comment: the text create new line if long text like picture 2

Comment: Try to add your `Text` widget

Comment: Are you wrapping you text widget in some sort of container? It would help if you could post the code so we could reproduce the error